# Why do my pipes make a loud noise when I use my washing machine?

Tags: water

I installed a new washing machine and every time the water shuts on or off it makes a loud noise in the pipes. Do the pipes need to be opened up more or less is it full of air or what.

Comment: What _sort_ of loud noise? Hissing? Banging? Howling at the moon? Please revise to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

What you likely have is something called "water hammering". It's especially prevalent in long runs of pipe. When a valve is suddenly turned off, as when the washing machine turns off the flow, the inertia of the flowing water has no place to go and hammers the pipes.  There are devices made that can minimize that.  They use an air gap for compression (water doesn't compress), to provide a buffer so the water can slow down without banging the pipes.   Product recommendations are off topic here, so I won't make any, but just search water hammering for various solutions.   It may take a plumber to install, but it's fixable, just depends how much you want to spend.

Comment: The bigger question is why did it just start now?

Comment: The new machine might have a faster acting valve.